# SSLException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown - what does it mean?

Tags: java, ssl, https, certificate, websphere

I am getting the "javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown" error when attempting to send a HTTPS message.

I believe the message is due to the endpoint not recognising the sent certificate or is rejecting it. But I want to be doubly sure this is a server issue and not a local client issue before I go barking up the wrong tree with my error analysis.

Can you guys please clarify the meaning of this error (google isn't helping much) and whether it is client or endpoint server related.

FYI: I am using Websphere Application Server 6.1

---

**Edit**: The stack trace is:

```
uk.gov.dwp.ifa.services.jef.CommandException:  javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.b(DashoA6275)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.a(DashoA6275)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.a(DashoA6275)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(DashoA6275)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:65)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:123)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod.writeRequestBody(EntityEnclosingMethod.java:502)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:1973)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:993)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:393)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:168)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:396)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:324)
    at uk.gov.dwp.ifa.services.jef.commands.HttpRequestCommand.postMessage(HttpRequestCommand.java:406)
    at uk.gov.dwp.ifa.services.jef.commands.HttpRequestCommand.evaluate(HttpRequestCommand.java:288)
    at uk.gov.dwp.ifa.services.jef.AbstractController.evaluate(AbstractController.java:46)
    at uk.gov.dwp.ifa.services.jef.SequentialAggregationController.evaluate(SequentialAggregationController.java:30)
    at uk.gov.dwp.ifa.services.jef.FlowMaster.evaluate(FlowMaster.java:86)
    at uk.gov.dwp.ifa.services.inbound.lite.servlet.InboundServlet.processRequest(InboundServlet.java:673)
    at uk.gov.dwp.ifa.services.inbound.lite.servlet.InboundServlet.doPost(InboundServlet.java:232)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:763)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:989)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:930)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:761)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:673)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:498)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:464)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:90)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:744)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1433)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:112)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:454)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:383)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:263)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:136)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:195)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:743)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:873)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1469)

    at uk.gov.dwp.ifa.services.jef.commands.HttpRequestCommand.evaluate(HttpRequestCommand.java:302)
    at uk.gov.dwp.ifa.services.jef.AbstractController.evaluate(AbstractController.java:46)
    at uk.gov.dwp.ifa.services.jef.SequentialAggregationController.evaluate(SequentialAggregationController.java:30)
    at uk.gov.dwp.ifa.services.jef.FlowMaster.evaluate(FlowMaster.java:86)
    at uk.gov.dwp.ifa.services.inbound.lite.servlet.InboundServlet.processRequest(InboundServlet.java:673)
    at uk.gov.dwp.ifa.services.inbound.lite.servlet.InboundServlet.doPost(InboundServlet.java:232)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:763)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:989)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:930)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:761)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:673)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:498)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:464)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:90)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:744)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1433)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:112)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:454)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:383)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:263)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:136)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:195)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:743)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:873)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1469)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.b(DashoA6275)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.a(DashoA6275)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.a(DashoA6275)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(DashoA6275)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:65)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:123)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod.writeRequestBody(EntityEnclosingMethod.java:502)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:1973)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:993)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:393)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:168)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:396)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:324)
    at uk.gov.dwp.ifa.services.jef.commands.HttpRequestCommand.postMessage(HttpRequestCommand.java:406)
    at uk.gov.dwp.ifa.services.jef.commands.HttpRequestCommand.evaluate(HttpRequestCommand.java:288)
    ... 32 more
```

Comment: Your exception says more than that, why make us guess? Post the whole stacktrace.

Comment: Is your web application trying to make a HTTPS call to an external component?

I can see the web request received by your classes (as an example - uk.gov.dwp.ifa.services.jef.commands.HttpRequestCommand). It seems to invoke some other component using Apache Commons HTTPClient.

What is this talking to? What are the certificates that are used for this communication?